# Bootstrapping: 632 vs n/2

Tags: bootstrap

Suppose I have $n$ individuals which are all either male or female and for each of which we can determine some quantity $X$. I want to decide whether there's a statistically significant difference in $X$ between males and females. Bootstrapping is one possibility to arrive at a $p$-value. When I read about bootstrapping, people usually recommend picking $n$ individuals with replacement at random, such that on average each bootstrapping sample contains $0.632n$ unique individuals. At the firm I work for, people perform bootstrapping by picking $n/2$ individuals $without$ replacement.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of these two possibilities? Which of the two gives me a better estimator of the "true" $p$-value?

Comment: Picking half the sample without replacement is not a form of bootstrapping I have ever encountered, and if you call this procedure (which may be quite valid for all I know) "bootstrapping", you may run into communication problems with people who associate the standard way of doing things with the term. Have you asked why people at your place use this nonstandard approach? They may have a good reason, or even a pointer to literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $p$-value is necessarily a function of the sample size. If you artificially half your sample, you will get $p$-values that are too large. If you have a small dataset, then the bias can be substantial. If your dataset is very large, then the difference may be small. If you feel uncomfortable about sampling with replacement, then you shouldn't, but if for organisational reasons there is nothing you can do about it, then you can consider the jackknife. This can be seen as an approximation of the bootstrap, but you don't have to tell them that...